# How to use nested foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I've successfully retrieved car make  and car name accordingly but I've no idea on how to retrieve image  for that particular car.I tried using nested foreach but didn't work as I expected.Instead of displaying particular image for a car id ,it shows the same image from last folder for all ids.

here's my code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_name,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $car[$row['carMake_id']][] = $row['carName'];
    //$car_name_id=$row['carName_id'];
    $gallery=$row['gallery'];
    //$car_make_id=$row['carMake_id'];
    //$car_gallery[$row['carName_id']][]=$row['gallery'];
}

foreach ($car as $carmake => $carname) {
    echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#0066cc;'><b>".$carmake ."</b></td></tr><tr>";
    foreach ($carname as $title) {
        echo "<td>".$title . "<br/>&nbsp;";
        ?>
        //this part displays image.. I want it to display according to the car name ($title)
        <img src="management/uploads/<?php echo $carmake;?>/<?php echo $gallery;?>" width="100" height="100"></td>
        <?php
    }
    echo'</tr>';
}
```

Also how do I retrieve all other information pertaining to a particular car inside the foreach?

Thanks.

EDITED PART:

```
$gallery[]=$row['gallery'];//inside while loop


 foreach ($car as $carmake => $carname)
                                        {

                                        echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#0066cc;'><b>".$carmake ."</b></td></tr><tr>";
foreach ($carname as $title) {
echo "<td>".$title . "<br/>&nbsp;";

foreach($gallery as $g)//new foreach to retreive images
{
echo $g;
}
?>

<img src="management/uploads/<?php echo $carmake;?>/<?php echo $g;?>" width="100" height="100"></td>
```

Comment: There's just a single `$gallery` variable, it contains the gallery from the last row. If you want it to be specific to the car name, you need to put it into the array.

Comment: It doesn't seem you even need a nested foreach. What is the value of `$row['gallery']`?

Comment: @Havenard , I did a mistake, the value of $gallery=$row['gallery']; is the image name I didn't use array unfortunately.

Comment: @Barmar  I tried using $gallery as an array like this: $gallery[]=$row['gallery']; and pulled out the value like this :foreach($gallery as $g)
           {
            echo $g;
           }    ......But it shows all the value regardless the car id.

Comment: If you do that, your gallery isn't related to the car makes or names. It needs to be an associative array. Anyway, see how I did it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `gallery` into the array.

```
<?php 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_name,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $car[$row['carMake_id']][] = $row;
    }

foreach ($car as $carmake => $carname)
    {
        echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#0066cc;'><b>".$carmake ."</b></td></tr><tr>";
        foreach ($carname as $title)
            {
                echo "<td>{$title['carName']}<br/>&nbsp;";
                //this part displays image.. I want it to display according to the car name ($title)
                echo "<img src='management/uploads/$carmake/{$title['gallery']}' width='100' height='100'></td>";
            }
        echo'</tr>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: it works... {$title['gallery']} ,is this what you call as associative array? And can I use it to call any other detail of that particular carname_id?

Comment: Yes, that's an associative array. You were already using an associative array to map `carMake_id` to an array of car names. I just added another dimension to it.